# Adding CSS to navigator to allow scroll mouse

Tags: php, css, wordpress, nav

I've a navigator that I added to a website by plugin using the wordpress platform. I have the option to add custom CSS code.

I currently need to add the scroll option that will appear in the menu automatically, when all the space below the menu is utilized and it is not possible to display the menu in its entirety.

Which CSS code should I need to use to do this function?

Here is my navigator (the side nav): https://ahab.ussl.co.il/sealing-and-construction-products/products/soldered-bituminous-sheets/

Please open the link above and see that the navigator at full...
and you will see that there is no option to scroll down anymore when the empty space under the navigator is used.

[I mean this scroll function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QywGr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
Overflow:auto;
```

can be added to most tags either inline, embedded or external stylesheet for the tag you want to see scroll bars and will present a scroll bar once the height of the tag has been filled.

```
section {
 top: 10px;
 padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 95%;
 overflow: auto;
 z-index: 0;
```

}

Comment: I tried to do so, but I think that all the CSS is Unnecessary Except for overflow: auto property. If you take a look at the page now: https://ahab.ussl.co.il/sealing-and-construction-products/products/soldered-bituminous-sheets/    you will see the changes but the overflow property didn't have any effect.

Comment: This is not a HTML document, this is a plugin that builded on wordpress platform, that means there is a PHP code. I think because of this there is no effect to the CSS property.

Comment: And apparently the plugin works on a particular layer that does not touch the global page built.